# Error importing database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, migration

I've been working on my site locally and i'm now trying to migrate it to a live. I export the local sql database and try to import it to the new database but it returns the error:

SQL query:

Table structure of table wpmedokonta_commentmeta

CREATE TABLE wpmedokonta_commentmeta (

meta_id BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , comment_id BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', meta_key VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL , meta_value LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, PRIMARY KEY ( meta_id ) , KEY comment_id ( comment_id ) , KEY meta_key ( meta_key ( 191 ) ) ) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

MySQL said: Documentation

1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

Anyone know why this happens? Not sure if it helps but i'm not using comments anywhere in my site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is because you have different MYSQL version.
check if the version of local server is same as live server.

Comment: The live server uses an older version of MySQL, so I had to save the output file from my local server for an older version. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You could also change `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8mb4` to `utf8` in your sql file.

Comment: Just converting utf8mb4_unicode_ci to utf8_general_ci in phpmyadmin panel worked...Thanks saviour !

Answer (score 0):

Replace utf8mb4_unicode_ci with with utf8_unicode_ci. It should work.

Also if you see InnoDB  in your database, replace InnoDB with MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I only had to maximize the compatibility when **exporting** on the local servidor.

For that, on the **Export Method** you need to chose "Custom - display all posible options" as the folow image:

[Export Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXqBb.png)

Then you need to check the box "Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with" and chose **MYSQL40**

[Compatibility with MYSQL40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl1lf.png)

Now your export file is done, just download it.

And last but not least, remember to put the same SQL compatibility (**MYSQL40**) on the importing step as folow:

[Import File Compatibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azEbB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in phpMyAdmin you first change the Server connection collation from 
`utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to `utf8_general_ci` as mentioned by @Kristy Kavada above.

If it still doesnt work make sure you have added a `;` in `use databasename;` as I had missed my semicolon and was getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Step one create a database with unique name and then open the database then import the database you have exported